# Get return 304 or Cannot get page on refresh

Tags: express, mongoose

my problem is quite a pain.

I dealed with the error : can't get / page_name on refresh page by adding this to my server.js

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
```

but now when I go to a page where I have functions like get / post. it return 304 ...

If i remove app.get('*' ... , I can't refresh without getting a blank page with 'cannot get / page_name , but if i go to it manually starting at the index, my get and post work perfectly.

the return of 304 is plain html when it should be json...

What can i do for enabling the refresh on any page without damaging my call to server?

my dep

```
"express": "4.15.2",
"morgan": "~1.0.0",
"mongoose": "4.9.8",
"body-parser": "1.17.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});` will catch all your requests (this is the `*` purpose)

So if you intend to keep this behaviour you may declare this route after every other ones.

About your error page in plain html:
To [handle errors](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) with express you have to set 
`app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500).json({error:'some message'})
})`

In order to understand why the / route does not match, you can do something like `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.route);
})`
to see what goes wrong

Comment: this is my website in construction. you can see my get in menu "Ajouter artist" . https://m-p-adrien-hascour.c9users.io/

Comment: Yes, your problem is that for any request you are serving the index.html file (try m-p-adrien-hascour.c9users.io/api/avbzzzs). You have to remove `*` or place `app.get('*',` in last position (after routers and /api/)

Comment: Besides, if you intent to serve other pages than index.html you can have a look to http://expressjs.com/fr/starter/static-files.html

Comment: OMG, that was "place app.get('*', in last position (after routers and /api/)"
I putted it after app.use('/api', router); and it works like a charm <3